# CsvHelper parsing fails for tab delimitted record

Tags: c#, .net, csvhelper

I have a Tab delimited file and using CsvHelper to parse it in .Net c#
Somehow its failing at 1 record and throws BadData, nothing seems wrong in record, i tried pasting in excel and used text to column, it worked fine.

Code to reproduce error

```
//add CsvHelper nuget package to project
//Create .txt file with below line and pass path of file into function
//copy text from https://gist.github.com/JitenPatoliya/9f9a15eb388c32f46231aa9fa35dd6e3
//Paste into your text file and try this code

private void TestCSvParser(string fullFilePath)
        {
            try
            {
                string ext = Path.GetExtension(fullFilePath);
                using var reader = new StreamReader(fullFilePath);
                using var csv = new CsvReader(reader, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
                csv.Configuration.BadDataFound = BadDataFound;
                csv.Configuration.DetectColumnCountChanges = true;
                if (ext.IsContains(".txt"))
                {
                    csv.Configuration.Delimiter = "\t";
                }
                while (csv.Read())
                {
                    var fullrow = csv.Context.RawRecord;
                    var record = csv.Parser.Read();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

            }
        }

private void BadDataFound(ReadingContext ctx)
        {
         //put debug point here
        }
```

Thank you and aprreciate you for spending time into this issue

Comment: Can you please post a sample data?

Comment: @Magnetron here's the raw data (Copying data in code making tab to space, that's why I used gist)

https://gist.github.com/JitenPatoliya/9f9a15eb388c32f46231aa9fa35dd6e3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, the problem is that one of your fields contains a `"`, which is a quotation character. You either have to escape it, or ignore quotes in your file. In the code bellow I'm ignoring. Also, if you'll be using `Parser.Read`, you shouldn't use `csv.Read` since it already advances to the next record before reading. So, your code becomes:

```
private void TestCSvParser(string fullFilePath)
{    
    try
    {
        string ext = Path.GetExtension(fullFilePath);
        using var reader = new StreamReader(fullFilePath);
        using var csv = new CsvReader(reader, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
        csv.Configuration.BadDataFound = BadDataFound;
        csv.Configuration.DetectColumnCountChanges = true;
        if (ext.Contains(".txt"))
        {
            csv.Configuration.Delimiter = "\t";                    
            csv.Configuration.IgnoreQuotes = true;
        }
        string[] record;
        while((record = csv.Parser.Read()) != null)
        {
            var fullrow = csv.Context.RawRecord;
        }                
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, I checked IgnoreQuotes property, but in this case I need to keep quotes, is there wa way i can keep it?

Comment: Seems like using ignore quotes works and keeps quotes in parsed text. I am doing more testing and will update you. Thanks for the help and pointing out multiple Read() that was skipping my record.

Comment: @JDev `IgnoreQuotes` doesn't remove the quotes from your data, it just don't treat them as a "csv quote". In csv, you can put a filed between quotes to escape things like line breaks and a delimiter character inside the data. for example: `"my first field,still first field",second field`. Note that if we don't use quotes, the parser would find 3 fields, instead of 2.